# Connection Refused for Android device as emulator using WebClient in VS 2019 on localhost

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, mobile

The Asp.Net Core web app I built is taken from a tutorial guide on Microsoft that targeted Phone 8. The controller in the backend had to upgrade by replacing HttpRequest calls with IActionResult. Data for the tutorial is pulled from an xml file. The web page loads up fine.
For the front end project Mobile app was used. For now I'm focusing on Android although IOS and UWP were included in the build. The Android manifest file has permissions for Internet and Network_State.
Visual Studio is running on a PC wired to the router. My Android phone uses the wifi from the router and for debugging is USB tethered to the PC.
WebClient is used to request data from the server app. A basic view of the code is:

```
class MainViewModel : WebClient
{
    //Assigned IP for local PC hosting the web page
    static string uriBase = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://192.168.50.250" : "http://localhost";
    //Port set in launchSetting.json for Http; Https is 8081
    const string urlPort = "8080";
    static string apiUrl = $"{uriBase}:{urlPort}/api/books";

    void LoadData()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(apiUrl)); 
    }

    private void webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                //recover the List<items> from json serialized object
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //put the error text into an item for display on the device
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the state of the firewall different responses are observed. Firewall on, the call times out and the inner exception says so. In fact, checking e.Result jumps immediately to the catch block. Disable the firewall and the call-back method picks up immediately with exception "Connection-Failure: Connection Refused".
Everything tried so far ends up with the same failure. Except, if I run an Android emulator in my Windows 10 home machine (using 10.0.2.2 for ip).
I have tried adding :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Before instantiating webClient. I have also included :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
       new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
            delegate
            { return true; }
        );
```

Which I assume is to take advantage of the development certificate.
At this point I will look into any further suggestion. Have not found anything that seems to get out of this anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: if you are using the built in development web server, it is generally set to refuse remote connections by default.  There are numerous existing articles and tutorials on how to enable remote connections

Comment: @Jason, No, I'm using an installed Browser typically Chrome. But I tried others: Edge and Brave; end up with the same response. Thanks though.

Comment: What are you talking about?  I didn't say anything about the browser.

Comment: @Jason, Sorry, I got confused about your suggestion. If you were referring to IIS Express, or even IIS, I disabled that in Windows Features as a step to assure that Kestrel would be used. Answers to questions of this nature recommended using Kestrel because of IIS behavior.

Comment: "Connection Refused" is usually a sign that the web server is refusing remote requests.  Have you tried connecting to the service endpoint using the browser **on the device** (or emulator) to verify connectivity?

Comment: Yes. With the emulator I end up with a different error: Connection-TrustFailure, Authentication Failed. Or after attempting to re-connect in the same session: Https Connection-SecureChannelFailure, Authentication failed because the remote party closed the transport stream. The emulator is a pain for the time it takes on Win-10 Home. Attempts to connect by calling localhost from a browser on my phone ends up with connection denied as well.

Comment: @Jason, After moving some ServicePointManager code to a class in the Android platform project, the emulator got the error as it had before and then on second request it worked. I may be on to  something.

Comment: However, with the device, still connection denied. Attempt to reach the page from a browser on the device and my search doesn't match any documents.

Comment: if you can't reach it from the browser then you have some sort of basic connectivity issue you need to solve